# Are there any Python packages which can fit Conditional Weibull Distributions

Tags: python, weibull-distribution

I'm trying to fit failure data which already has a burn in time, and Im in need to use the Conditional Weibull Distribution. Are there any Python packages which have this distribution implemented?

Comment: what does burn-in time mean in this context?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/ragulpr/wtte-rnn
A weibull time series regression module built on TensorFlow keras.

Generally I can highly recommend TensorFlow Probability and associated packages for any statistical modeling, while leveraging power and expressiveness of neural networks.
For example take a look at https://probflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/time_to_event.html

Built on TensorFlow Probability ( which has Weibull as one of 100s of implemented distributions).

Answer (score 1):

In R you can use the `brms` package (a really great tool for incredibly flexible modelling) to create such a (Bayesian) time-to-event regression model with notation like this:

```
brm( formula = event_time | trunc(lb = burn_in_time) + cens(censored) ~ predictors,
     family = weibull(link = "log", link_shape = "log")
```

where I assume there is a variable that gives a `burn_in_time` during which items were not at risk in order to be part of your dataset (and that it is always `< event_time` and you assume that from time zero all records have the same Weibull distribution, you just start being in the current datasets after different times) and a variable with a `censored` indicator with 0 for non-censored observations and 1 for right-censored ones (see the [brms documentation](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/reference/brmsformula.html)).

Sure, this is not a Python package, but what it actually does in the background is create [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/) code for the model and compile it. You can get the Stan code via the `make_stancode` function and then use it with a Python interface to Stan like `PyStan` (or you call R from Python using something like `rpy2`). There's also the alternative of using [`pybrms`](https://github.com/adamhaber/pybrms), but I have no experience with that.

For all of the above, you of course need to be comfortable with a Bayesian framework and would probably want to at least specify weakly informative priors.